# WPF; How Deselect all my selected items when click on empty space in my ListView

Tags: wpf, listview

When i have several (or even one) `selected items` and i press simple `click` on empty space in my `ListView` (empty space = not row) i want to deselect all my selected items.

This is my deselect all item function:

```
private void DeselectAllListViewItems()
{
    MyListView.SelectedItems.Clear();
}
```

I try to take the selected index with this function:

```
private void MyListView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (MyListView.SelectedIndex == -1)
        DeselectAllListViewItems();
}
```

But in case i have several selected items (or one..) the selected index will never be -1.
So how can i distinguish that my `mouse click` is on empty space and not on item row ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle the event when click on empty space?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554425/how-to-handle-the-event-when-click-on-empty-space)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF Listbox remove selection by clicking on a blank spot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23133527/wpf-listbox-remove-selection-by-clicking-on-a-blank-spot)

Answer (score 16):

The code below works quite well.

```
private void MyListView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    HitTestResult r = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(this, e.GetPosition(this));
    if (r.VisualHit.GetType() != typeof(ListBoxItem))
        listView1.UnselectAll();
}
```

[WPF Listbox remove selection by clicking on a blank spot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23133527/wpf-listbox-remove-selection-by-clicking-on-a-blank-spot)